Let X be a topological space. A is subset of X, Compact in X. if Y is subset of A, then is closure of Y respect to X reside in A?
I'm just qurious about the relationship between compactness of superset A and it's subset Y's closure, assuming 1) X is hausdorff 2) X is not hausdorff
of Course in case 1), A is compact, so Y's closure is in A. But what if X is not hausdorff and only satisfy lower seperation axioms? like T1 or even only T0. Is there difference in result?

Generally if $X$ is any topological space, and $A$ is any subset of $X$, then "for every subset $Y$ of $A$, the closure of $Y$ in $X$ is a subset of $A$" is equivalent to $A$ being closed in $X$ (think about taking $Y = A$). So you're essentially asking for a space with a compact subset which is not closed. So see eg here.
